# How can I remove an existing <Marker> component from <Map> in react js?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have the following return :

```
import {Map, Marker} from 'google-maps-react';
class SimpleMap extends Component{ 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        marker: {
            available: false,
            position: {
                lat: lathere,
                lng: lnghere
            }
        }
    };
  }
  onClick = (t, map, coord) => {
      const {latLng} = coord;
      let {marker} = this.state;
      marker.position.lat = latLng.lat();
      marker.position.lng = latLng.lng();
      this.setState({marker});
};
  render(){
  const {marker} = this.state;
  return (<Map
     google={this.props.google}
     zoom={8}
     initialCenter={{position here}}
     onClick={this.onClick}>
        <Marker position={marker.position}/>
  </Map>);
}}
```

How can I remove the current marker when I click again on the map? I've searched for some solutions but in each of them there were objects instantiated with `new google.maps.map` & `new google.maps.marker`  saved as global variables and use reference from one to another so they could remove the marker's map. How can I do that in ReactJS?

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to HMehmood1's answer [here](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/issues/179). You just need to explicitly add the `lat` and `lng` in `<Marker>`. E.g:

```
<Marker position={{ lat: marker.position.lat, lng: marker.position.lng }}/>
```